Game Theory Brainteaser
Seeking help / thought process guidance on the following interview problem, which seems centred on game theory
Setup: there’s a number X which we can measure once with error following N(0, 1). We can choose whether to receive $X (negative means lose money)
a) When do we choose to receive X?
b) Now another agent can also measure X with iid error, and choose to receive X before you (if they do so we can no longer receive X). What’s the strategy now?
c) Back to single-player.  Now after measuring, X moves up/down by one every second with even probability. We cannot observe again but know each second which direction X moves. What’s the strategy?
d) Same as c) except the other agent comes back in and has the same information/setup (iid measure, can see X’s moves, can collect before us each second). What’s the best strategy now?
For a), I was thinking we should take the observed value as the best estimate and accept if it is positive. For b), I guess if the other player doesn’t accept when we see a positive value, that makes it more likely the true value is lower?
For (b), suppose we observe y_1 = X + e_1, and the other agent observes y_2 = X + e_2.
Then I guess we want to compute E(X | y2 < 0) = y_1 - E(e_1 | y_1 - e_1 + e_2 < 0)?
I tried bashing it out, but this seems to require some convolution integral, or likely that I'm overcomplicating it...

i dont think you have provided enough info about this or been precise enough.

Do all agents make choices based on whatever has the highest expected payoff? Or is the question supposed to be more open ended, with a discussion of utility functions?

Seems fair to assume that $X$ is fairly close to 0 and the game is repeated many times. If that is indeed the case, then you can justify maximising expectation.

Fair point all - I think this is more intended as a question for open discussion. Maximising EV is probably the underlying intention, but there may be some practical considerations with regards to trading too.
